# Help following a proof reducing a PDE to coupled ODEs

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations

I'm having trouble following the following proof.

Given 
$$\rho_a(a,t)+\rho_t(a,t)+\mu(P(t))\rho(a,t)=0~~~~(1.1)$$
$$B(t)=\rho(0,t)=\int_0^\infty \beta(a,P(t))\rho(a,t)da~~~(1.2)$$
$$P(t)=\int_0^\infty \rho(a,t)da~~~(1.3)$$
where the functions $\mu(P)$ and $\beta(a,P)~(a\geq 0,P\geq 0)$ are assumed prescribed, the corresponding initial-value problem consists in finding a solution $\rho(a,t)$ of (1.1) which satisfies the initial condition $\rho(a,0)=\phi(a)$.

Now let $g$ be a (sufficiently nice) function of $a$ with
$$g(a)\rho(a,t)\rightarrow 0~~\text{as}~~a\rightarrow\infty~~~(2),$$
and defining
$$G(t)=\int_0^\infty g(a)\rho(a)da,$$
and
$$H(t)=\int_0^\infty g'(a)\rho(a)da,$$
then 
$$ \dot{G}+\mu(P)G -g(0)B=H.~~~(3)$$

Gurtin, M.E. and MacCamy, R.C. 1978. Some simple models for nonlinear age-dependent population dynamics. Mathematical Biosciences, 43:199-211.

The proof is

1. Multiply (1.1) by $g$ and integrate from $a=0$ to $a=\infty$, giving
   $$\dot{G}(t) + \int_0^\infty g(a)\rho_a(a,t)da+\mu(P)G(t)=0$$
2. Integrate the second term by parts and use (2), then (3) follows.

It's the use of (2) that I don't understand. If I carry out the integration I get
$$\dot{G}(t) + g(a)\rho(a,t) + \mu(P)G(t)=H.$$
So (2) is being used to set $a=0$ in the second term. Can someone help me understand this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting that it is a definite integral which needs to be evaluated at the endpoints:

$$\dot{G}(t) + g(a)\rho(a,t)]^\infty_0 + \mu(P)G(t) = H(t)$$
$$\dot{G}(t) + \left[g(\infty)\rho(\infty,t)-g(0)\rho(0,t)\right] + \mu(P)G(t) = H(t)$$
then using (2)
$$\dot{G}(t) - g(0)\rho(0,t)+\mu(P)G(t)=H(t)$$
$$\dot{G}(t) + \mu(P)G(t) - g(0)B(t)=H(t).$$